# Python: what float(2**53+3) will be

Tags: python

We know that python float number is 64bit. And I take a test:

```
float(2**53) is 9007199254740992.0,
```

and it is ok

```
float(2**53+1) is also 9007199254740992.0,
```

and it is ok, because the last 1 can not be presented in 64bit binary.

```
float(2**53+3) is equal to float(2**53+2),
```

but the result of

```
float(2**53+3) is **9007199254740996.0**
```

How does the float number work in python ?

Comment: The same way that `double` works in C.

Comment: On my system, `float(2*53+2) == 108.0` and `float(2*53+3) == 109.0`. I suspect such overflow is undefined behavior and that you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.6768)

Comment: @WaleedKhan, that's `**` not `*`.

Comment: [Why Do Computers Suck at Math?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/05/why-do-computers-suck-at-math.html)

Comment: Just to round out the suggested articles, here's another take on it: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @TimS., I think the poster understands that not all floating point numbers can be represented. The question is why it's rounding the way it did, and I think that's a good topic to pursue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because you're in the default IEEE rounding mode, ["round to even"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even).

That is to say, when rounding a value exactly half way between two representable values, the result chosen is one with a 0 in the last bit of the significand.

In this case since you're losing one bit of precision, that amounts to "round to a multiple of 4".

Hence the value `9007199254740995` rounds to the representable value `9007199254740996.0`, and not the equally-close and also representable value `9007199254740994.0`

Meanwhile the value `9007199254740993` rounds to `9007199254740992.0`, also not `9007199254740994.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `2**53+3` is an `int64`, so there is no problem and if you evaluate it in python it will give you the correct answer `9007199254740995`.

However, `float64` has 52 bits for the fraction part, so when you convert `9007199254740995` to `float64` by doing `float(2**53+3)`, you lose precision and get rounded to a nearby number: `9007199254740996.0`.

Comment: But why *that* particular number and not 9007199254740994.0 which is also representable? Especially when `float(9007199254740993)` returns 9007199254740992.0.

Comment: @SteveJessop, I'm not familiar enough with the rounding modes to have an answer off the top of my head, and no time at the moment to research it.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point IEEE standard, 64bits floats have a precision of 52 bits + 1 sign bit.

That means any number requiring more than 52 significant bits is rounded to 52 significant bits.

In your case, you have 53 significant bits, meaning the last one is discarded/rounded/something.